# How can I download all git LFS files in batches on mac and linux?

Tags: git, git-clone, git-lfs

When I'm running git lfs clone somerepository in Windows, I've got the following output

```
Cloning into 'somerepository'...
remote: Counting objects: 24028, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5003/5003), done.
remote: Total 24028 (delta 7376), reused 23762 (delta 7265)
Receiving objects: 100% (24028/24028), 7.12 MiB | 3.86 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (7376/7376), done.
Git LFS: (57 of 57 files) 1.57 GB / 1.57 GB
```

Last line means git downloaded al files in a few batches (not 1 file at time like git pull) and it's quite quick.

In linux and mac instead, the same command does only the first 6 steps and nor the last one, leaving all LFS-tracked files only as a pointer. If I do a fetch/checkout/pull, git download the content one file at the time andvery slowly. I compared all configuration amongst different Linux/Windows/Mac system and behaviour are all the same with latest version of git and git-lfs.

I'd like to know what is the last command that git lfs clone run and how to trigger it manually or automatically even on Linux and Mac.

Thanks

Comment: Git LFS is still not stable yet and been using it for last 3 months we came across many different issues that a tool for prod shouldnt have.. anyway I suggestion is to make sure to use always latest version and not rely on default installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked as expected to me on a Gerrit server:

```
> git lfs clone https://USER@GERRIT-SERVER/a/REPOSITORY
Cloning into 'REPOSITORY'...
remote: Counting objects: 5, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (5/5)
remote: Total 929 (delta 0), reused 929 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (929/929), 151.10 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (275/275), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Git LFS: (2 of 2 files) 1.77 MB / 1.77 MB

> git --version
git version 2.7.4

> git lfs version
git-lfs/1.5.3 (GitHub; linux amd64; go 1.7.4; git 23455e48)
```

$HOME/.gitconfig LFS contents:

```
[filter "lfs"]
    clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
    smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
    process = git-lfs filter-process
    required = true
```

Comment: # git --version
git version 2.1.4
# git lfs version
git-lfs/1.5.5 (GitHub; linux amd64; go 1.7.4; git c2dcd6f5)
How do you upgrade to 2.7.4? I try to follow this http://lifeonubuntu.com/upgrading-ubuntu-to-use-the-latest-git-version/ but I cant upgrade to latest stable 2.11

Comment: Anyway, on Mac git --version is 2.10 and still doesnt execute the last step. Could you please post your git config -l

Comment: Added. Just to confirm: are you executing "git lfs clone ..." and not "git clone ...", right?